# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal - Mongodb aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

Below is my mongodb aggregate query which is throwing error

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):12:7

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{
   $match: {
           "countries" : {$in : ["USA"] },
           "tomatoes.viewer.rating" : {"$gte" : 3 }
          }
},
{ 
   $project: {
          "num_favs" : { "$filter": {
                                      input: "$cast" ,
                                       as: "num",
                                       cond: { $in:["$$num", [ "Sandra Bullock",
                                                               "Tom Hanks",
                                                               "Julia Roberts",
                                                               "Kevin Spacey",
                                                               "George Clooney"] ]}
                                   }
                       }
        }
}

]);
```

Sample record of the collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a1390f29313caabcd421c"),
        "title" : "A Turn of the Century Illusionist",
        "year" : 1899,
        "runtime" : 1,
        "cast" : [
            "Georges M�li�s"
        ],
        "lastupdated" : "2015-08-29 00:21:21.547000000",
        "type" : "movie",
         "directors" : [
            "Georges M�li�s"
         ],
        "imdb" : {
            "rating" : 6.6,
            "votes" : 580,
            "id" : 246
        },
        "countries" : [
            "France"
        ],
        "genres" : [
            "Short"
        ],
        "tomatoes" : {
                "viewer" : {
                       "rating" : 3.8,
                        "numReviews" : 32
                },
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2015-08-20T18:46:44Z")
        }
    }
```

Any idea  what is that I am missing ?

Comment: could you please share your schema.

Comment: As I am not sure about the structure of $favorites, is its array or object.

Comment: favorites is an array of strings...

Comment: also  added sample doc to the question

Comment: Where is "favorites" field in your sample doc?

Comment: Its cast and not favorites , modified the query , but still same issue

Comment: Can you let me know your desired result? What count do you need to find?